# Navigating between screens having two separate react native files

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and I want to navigate between screens. I have two sample files

```
#App.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Home from './src/Home';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Home/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFEB3B',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and another file

```
#Home.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>User</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Contractor</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500',
    color:'#212121',
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  button: {
    width:300,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor:'#FCE4EC',
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical:16

  }
});
```

How do I make it that when either User or Contractor are clicked in Home.js file they take me to different screens preferably using stacknavigator. I tried the documentation but can't seem to figure out the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this easily using [StackNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html) offered by [react-navigation library](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation).

Here is the idea:
In the App.js file you have to refer to the stacknavigator/parent of your navigation.

```
#App.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './src/Home';
import Contractor from './src/Contractor';
import User from './src/User';

const Main = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: Home
  },
  UserScreen: {
    screen: User,
  },
  ContractorScreen: {
    screen: Contractor,
  },
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Main/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFEB3B',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Home file:

```
#Home.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} 
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'UserScreen'})}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>User</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'ContractorScreen'})}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Contractor</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500',
    color:'#212121',
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  button: {
    width:300,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor:'#FCE4EC',
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingVertical:16

  }
});
```

User file:

```
#User.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>I am the User screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500',
    color:'#212121',
    textAlign:'center'
});
```

And finally, Contractor file:

```
#Contractor.js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default class Contractor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>I am the Contractor screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:'500',
    color:'#212121',
    textAlign:'center'
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I am beginning to get some insight into it

Comment: @omar-salah-elboredy After nearly a year, would you add anything to this answer? Is this still the best way to split your code in your opinion? I just picked up RN and stumbled upon this question, your answer helped me out, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AppNavigation from './src/NavigationContainer';

function App() {
  return <AppNavigation />;
}

export default App;
```

NavigationContainer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function AppNavigation() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1">
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen1" component={Screen1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppNavigation;
```

Screen1.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function Screen1({ navigation }) {
return (
    <View>
    <Text>Screen 1</Text>
    <Button
        title="Go Screen 2"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2')}
    />
    </View>
);
}

export default Screen1;
```

Screen2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

function Screen2({ navigation }) {
return (
    <View>
    <Text>Screen 2</Text>
    <Button
        title="Back Screen 1"
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
    />
    </View>
);
}

export default Screen2;
```

[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEEPY.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).